# Multilingual support in Kendo UI Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, kendo-ui

I am new to Kendo UI chart ,i need to implement **localization in Kendo UI Chart** that should support different languages dynamically.

**Reply me as soon as possible please**

THANKS IN ADVANCE